# Is the following Markov Chain a martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, martingales

Say I have a finite, ergodic Markov chain with states ${0,1,2,3}$ and  with the following transition matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}     
\frac{7}{10} & \frac{3}{10} & 0 &0\\
\frac{1}{10} & \frac{6}{10} & \frac{3}{10}  &0\\
0 & \frac{3}{10} & \frac{6}{10} & \frac{1}{10} \\
0& 0& \frac{3}{10} & \frac{7}{10}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

If I define $M_n$ to be the value of the state (so either $0,1,2$ or $3$) divided by $5$ at time $n$, is $M_n$ a martingale? I am inclined to believe it is not because the expected value of $M_{n+1}$ given the filtration at $n$ is not equal to $M_n$ (at least by my calculations).

Comment: If $(M_n)$ is a martingale then $E(M_{n+1}\mid M_n=0)=0$. Hence...

Comment: Then it can't be a Martingale because if $M_n = 0$, then $\mathbb{E}(M_{n+1})$ is $\frac{3}{50}$ which is $\neq 0$, correct?

Comment: Yes. Close the question?

Comment: Sure, by answering it?

Comment: Please do (note that askers are allowed to answer their own questions).

Answer (score 3):

For every martingale $(M_n)$, $\mathbb{E}(M_{n+1} | M_n ) = M_n$. But here, $\mathbb{E}(M_{n+1}|M_n=0) = \frac{3}{50}$. Therefore, $(M_n)$ is not a martingale.